# Changing Ajaxsource by Combobox

Tags: datatables

I've set my datatables like the scripts below

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                'bProcessing': true,
                'bServerSide': true,
                'bAutoWidth': false,
                'sAjaxSource': 'code1.php'
 } );
```

I want to change this ajaxsource (refresh the datatable) everytime users change a combobox in my application, so I added scripts below

```
$( "#cmbo" ).change(function() {
             var a = $( "#cmbo" ).val();
             var newUrl = 'code2.php?act='+a;
             $('#example').fnReloadAjax(newUrl);
 });
```

the problem is.. the datatables didn't show any changes.
No refresh-tables, no processes.
I need to have the contents in my datatables change as users change the combobox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oTable.fnDraw(); use redraw function of datatable at --> http://datatables.net/api => Redraw the table